# Global Optimization with bounds in R

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

I am looking for an optimzier that minimizes a least square problem (non-linear) for a global minimum with constraints.

I was trying to use SANN optimization in R but realised that it doesnt allow constaints. I actually just want to bind my constraint to >0 and <1.

Is there a package available for that?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the base `optim` function with setting the `lower` and `upper` parameters to 0 and 1, respectively, and the `gr` parameter to `"L-BFGS-B"`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mention that I already use optim function. But it's not searching for global minimum. I have a heterogenic sample that is very susceptible to the initial parameter.

Comment: I see. I'm not an expert on this, but I suppose you could apply optim with `"L-BFGS-B"` over a grid of initial values supplied to `par` and then choose the best optimised parameters.

Or else you could use "SANN", but change your initial objective function such that it's automatically constrained. For example, if you really want to minimise wrt `\beta` but `\beta` must lie between 0 and 1, then you could instead instead minimise wrt `tau` and replace `beta` by `exp(\tau)/(1+exp(\tau))` (the logit function) in your objective function. It'll always be between 0 and 1 then.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to change my initial objective function

Answer (score 1):

You could apply `optim` with "L-BFGS-B", which directly allows constraints. If the results are very sensitive to initial parameters, then you could minimise over a grid of initial values supplied to `par` and then choose the parameters that give the best result.

You could also use "SANN" with `optim` (or any other unconstrained optimiser), but change your initial objective function such that it's automatically constrained. For example, if you really want to minimise wrt `\beta` but `\beta` must lie between 0 and 1, then you could instead instead minimise wrt `\tau` and replace `\beta` by `exp(\tau)/(1+exp(\tau))` (the logit function) in your objective function. It'll always be between 0 and 1 then.